# A question on Hölder condition.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, uniform-continuity, holder-spaces

Suppose $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ satisfies the Hölder condition, *i.e.* there are constant $\alpha>0$ and $L>0$ such that
$$
\|f(x) - f(y)\|\leq L\cdot \|x - y\|^{\alpha},\quad \mbox{ for all } x,y\in \mathbb{R}^{n}.
$$
It is well known that if
$\alpha>1$ and $U$ is open and connected, then $f$ is differentiable and constant.

Is there an example of a continuous Hölder application  $ f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ that satisfies the conditions below?

- $n>1$, $\alpha>1$ and $f$ is not constant;
- $f$ is not differentiable at all points of the sequence  $\{x_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}\subset U$;
- $\{x_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}\subset U$ has an infinite number of accumulation points;
- $f$  is not differentiable at all accumulation points of the sequence;

Comment: Did you mean to write $\alpha > 0$ on the first line and $\alpha > 1$ on the third line?

Comment: @JoseAvilez ,  I fixed the mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In any dimension, as long as $U$ is an open set, then an $\alpha$-Hölder continuous function with $\alpha>1$ will be (locally) constant: The condition
$$
\dfrac{\| f(x)-f(y)\|}{\| x-y\|} \leq L\| x-y\|^{\alpha-1},\qquad x\neq y,
$$
implies that the derivative of $f$ at any given $x\in U$ is zero (since the zero linear transformation works in having a limit for the quotient on the left).